# "One-shot" way to change Wagtail pages' owner

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail

Is there a clean and fast way to change Wagtail pages' owner? In my project I have page objects which I'd want to keep for production but were created by a `non pk=1` user, so fixtures would have trouble when either the user's pk or natural foreign key would not exist in the Users database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with some assumptions it can be done with next code:

```
owner = User.objects.get(some condition to get owner)
Page.objects.filter(some condition to filter pages for updating).update(owner=owner)
```

Comment: Didn't think about that... Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @FidelLeon so, please, approve my answer.